# Getting error when trying to fetch data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to fetch data from a Mysql database using PHP, the following code gets a message:

**Getting error:**

> undefined variable result.

```
<?php 
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
echo <<<_END
 <form action="fetchdata.php" method="post"><pre>
   Enter Country <input type="text" name="field">  
                <input type="submit" value="Display Records">
 </pre></form>
_END;

if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
  $field=$_post($conn,'field');
  $query="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Country = '$field'";
  $result=$conn->query($query);
  if (!$result) die($conn->error);
  }

$rows = $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Campbell Menzies  you have answers below. check them and mark+up-vote one as accepted answer. You can up-vote others too if they are useful.Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  I am awre of SQL injection, but this is a closed environment - localhost and server on USB - so not worrying about that yet.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
  $field=$_post($conn,'field');
```

Maybe you mean

```
  $field=$_POST['field'];
```

Additionally you use $result at the end, even when it is not defined:

```
$rows = $result->num_rows;
```

Also you never output any data and print it. You just store it in variables.

In any case: What you are doing there by writing form data directly into a query string, is dangerous. I recommend you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) together with [Named Parameters](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Named_Placeholders). Also maybe read up about [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Here is another stackoverflow question with a nice answer, regarding SQL injections. It includes both PDO and mysqli: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/6637731

Comment: `$rows = $result->num_rows;` will never be reached if  `$result` is not defined: `if (!$result) die($conn->error);`

Comment: The row will be reached when !isset($_POST['field']), the if you are writing about is inside anotehr if.

Answer (score 0):

Without telling how request to this code is done, one guess is that  `isset($_POST['field'])` returns `false`, hence variable `$result` is never defined but you use it anyway below in `$result->num_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the below line. It should be

`$field=$_POST['field'];`

not

`$field=$_post($conn,'field');`